# What is the difference between test functions and basis functions of the FEM?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I'm a novice to the finite elements method (FEM) and I'm finding quite hard to find the actual difference between Test functions and Basis functions.

I would be glad if somone could explain me that and point out **how can they differ from one another and in which cases its useful that they differ (or not).**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They *are* completely different terms.

The following answer summarizes the derivation of FEM, but not in detail.
If you need more details let me know or check the literature.

---

Let's start with the strong formulation Laplace Equation in $Ω⊂ℝ^d$: 
\begin{align*}-Δu&=f\quad\text{ in }Ω \\
u&=0\quad \text{ on }Ω
\end{align*}

The weak formulation is: Find $u∈V_1$ such that: 
$$(∇u,∇φ) = (f,φ), \qquad ∀φ∈V_2. \label{b}\tag{1}$$

If $V_1=V_2$ these methods are named Galerkin-Methods, otherwise Petrov-Galerkin-Methods. 
$V_1$ is called Ansatz-space, and $V_2$ is called Test-space. The name comes from "testing" (multiplying) the original strong formulation. Hence, the name test-function for functions $φ∈V_2$.

For convenience lets just consider Galerkin-Methods in this answer:  $$V:=V_1=V_2.$$ 
(For example $V=H^1_0(Ω)$.)
The weak formulation \eqref{b} can't be solved on a computer as it is. We need to choose a finite dimensional subspace $V_h⊂V$, to get the following (approximated) weak equation: Find $u_h∈V_h$, such that
$$(∇u_h,∇φ_h) = (f,φ_h), \qquad ∀φ_h∈V_h. \label{c}\tag{2}$$

Still this equation can't be solved on a computer. $V_h$ is finite dimensional, but that does not mean that there is a finite amount of $φ_h∈V_h$. But since that space is finite dimensional it is sufficient to test with a basis. So let $\{φ_h^i, i=1,…,n\}$  be a basis of $V_h$. Then the following equation system is equivalent to \eqref{c}: 
$$(∇u_h,∇φ^i_h) = (f,φ^i_h), \qquad ∀ i=1,…,n. \label{a}\tag{3}$$

The next step would be to express $u_h$ in the basis with $u_h(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n u_h^jφ_h^j(x)$, plug it in and derive the linear equation system $\textbf{A}_h\textbf{u}_h = \textbf{f}.$

Everything so far has been done with arbitrary function spaces. The idea of FEM is just to choose $V_h$ as a local polynomial space, e.g. piecewise  bi-linear functions, in which you can easily find a basis.

---

The test-function is the function $φ$ with which you multiply the equation. Using the names from above $φ$ is an element of $V$, to be exact of $V_{2}$.
A basis-function $φ_h^i$ is part of *a* basis of the finite dimensional subspace $V_h⊂V.$

In equation \eqref{a} where you multiply with a basis-function $φ_h^i$, that basis-function is also a test-function.
In the representation $u_h(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n u_h^jφ_h^j(x)$, I would not call $φ_h^j$ a test-function, as you don't test anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer, perfect. I had that confusion because, from the few examples I've seen, the basis functions and the test functions were the same.